# How to allow users to attach multiple images to a Django post using a ModelForm and formset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm building a Django app that allows users to create posts and attach images to those posts. Each user can create multiple posts, and each post can have multiple images. I'm using a ModelForm to handle the creation of posts, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the creation of the images associated with each post.

Here's my current code:

**models.py**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()

class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/')
```

**forms.py**

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body']
```

**views.py**

```py
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form})
```

What's the best way to modify my code to allow users to attach multiple images to their posts when they create them? How can I modify the PostForm to handle this, and how should I modify the create_post view to save the images along with the post? Any help is greatly appreciated!